# Customizing sharepoint 2010 Quick Launch bar for certain pages only

Tags: 2010, quick-launch

I am rolling out a number of custom pages using a page template feature approach. I am also using a custom master page for these pages.
As part of the design, we would like the Quick Launch menu for the custom pages to hide Libraries and Discussion categories, and add a few custom links. 
I found [How to customize Quick Launch bar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms427791.aspx#) walkthrough. However, the changes in it are global to the site. Is there a way to localize changes to a specific page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already answered half of your question. You cannot customize Quick Launch by changing [SPNavigationNodeCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms427791.aspx) on server side because your changes are then applied globally.

So you are left with one reasonable option - to do it on client side with some javascript. I would suggest that you use [jQuery](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yojoshi/archive/2010/06/17/using-jquery-with-sharepoint-2010.aspx) for the sake of simplicity. To hide Libraries header you can use following script:

```js
$("div[id*='V4QuickLaunchMenu'] span:contains('Libraries')").parents("li").hide()
```

You can simply add your javascript to page by using Content Editor WebPart : http://sptwentyten.wordpress.com/2010/08/31/insert-javascript-into-a-content-editor-web-part-cewp/

General disadvantage of using client side script for this manipulation is that header can be visible for a brief moment before script loads and executes.

Answer (score 0):

The best suggestion I can make is wrap the desired change functionality into a web part and only put that web part on the pages you want to affect.  You can do pretty much anything you would conceivable want to do with a master page with a couple lines of server-side code or javascript.

The timing of your question is good, as I'll be publishing a freebie web part (...along with source) that does this early-mid next week.  You just add it to the page (it's hidden) and then configure in the web part settings what you want to hide.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this method and for me it works fine!

http://webdevshareetc.blogspot.it/2012/09/sharepoint-2010-customizing-quick.html

Bye!

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint.se! While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer] for general guidelines.